# how to reduce space between Figure legend and actual image in R Markdown

Tags: label, markdown, figure, caption

I am using the following command to include images in my R Markdown.

```
![Legend of the figure.\label{fig3}](image.pdf){width=90%}
```

However, it adds a lot of space between the actual image and its legend/label at the bottom (Figure 1: ...). Any ideas on how to reduce this space?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, a quick mockup shows expected space, knitting to HTML. Otherwise, you could use CSS to customise `div.figure > img` or `p.caption`:

```
---
title: "test.Rmd"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

Text before.

![Legend of the figure.\label{fig3}](https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png){width=90%}

Text after.
```